# Git, just abandon modified files before add/commit them

Tags: git

I got confused with Git !!

I have some files which have added and committed to master branch before.
NOw, I've made some changes in some files,but **before** adding and committing these modifications, I just want to abandon whatever I've done and come back to my previous , peaceful, state !!

What was the command ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are on the staging area (you `git add`ed them):

```
git reset HEAD file1 file2
git checkout file1 file2
```

If they are on the working area:

```
git checkout file1 file2
```

I also suggest giving [Adam Dymitruk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11232169/604041) a look (at least the first part). He explains how to save your changes before canceling them.

Comment: `git checkout` was the answer ..  Thanks :)

Comment: Your solution is also destructive.

Comment: Hey you! Yes you, the guy who down voted me! Would you explain why?!

Comment: wasn't me.. I'm thinking it's about the fact that you require the listing of specific files.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk: I wasn't targeting you. That was a joke. :) -- Concerning the listing of files, what else could I use to illustrate the example? An asterisk? -- Soask: Please accept my answer. :)

Comment: why is this the accepted answer? why would you recommend an operation with no safety net?

Comment: It has been accepted because it's simple, straight to the goal, and answers the OP's question. He clearly said *I just want to abandon whatever I've done and come back to my previous , peaceful, state*, which means that he knows what he's doing and doesn't need what you call a *safety net*. Your answer is interesting but full of bloat and complicated stuff (for a newbie).

Comment: Noobs should be especially weary of a lack of a safety net. It is the exact reason this should *not* be the accepted answer. It is unsafe and not for noobs to form a habit out of. Take a look at the voting and see who agrees with you.

Comment: All that whining because your answer didn't get accepted... How lame. -- I won't repeat what I have already explained. Enjoy your up votes and stop complaining, answering a question the most clearly possible is fair enough for me.

Comment: No whining. Noobs will cut themselves. SO is where noobs end up. Do the math.

Answer (score 4):

**WARNING! `git reset --hard` and `git checkout -- some files` has no undo! Be careful!**

The best thing to do is to stash what you don't think you need with

```
git stash -u
```

(the -u will include not yet tracked files as well as tracked ones). Now you are back to a clean state. In case you *did* have something important in there and realized later, you can inspect your stash to find it again. To get them back again, you can

```
git stash pop
```

to "erase" them again

```
git stash -u
```

Don't do anything without a safety net.

**To do this on a subset of files, or parts of files, you can:**

```
git add -A && git stash save --patch
```

Unfortunately patch doesn't work with untracked files for stash.

If all your changes involve just tracked files or you don't care about untracked files hanging around, you can skip the git add and just do this:

```
git stash save --patch
```

You will then be prompted for what you want to stash (effectively removing it). This way you can reset only certain changes if you wish - safely.

**Any ignored files are untouched. To wipe them,**

```
git clean -xdf
```

this is permanent, since they are ignored, it's not as important to have a backup of them.

Comment: I've been burned by this before.. I rarely reset --hard now.

Comment: Btw, your warning isn't bold.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain why this is a bad answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just run this:

```
git clean -dfx
git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you want to do here.  If your goal is to replace your last commit with a new commit, `git add` the files you want to update as usual and then `git commit --amend`.  This will create a new commit whose parent is the current commit's parent.  You can also accomplish this with `git reset --soft HEAD^` followed by `git commit`.

Comment: Thanks ... `git checkout` was the answer .. I didn't add my new changes .

Comment: be careful, you can't get back what you had there before if you change your mind later.